# Why does a router ping failure respond using a different IP?

Tags: windows, routing, router

From Windows CMD, when trying to ping another computer on our internal LAN, the IP obviously fails to respond.  However the reply of "Destination host unreachable." comes from yet a different IP, and not that of the router.

In my network, the gateway is 10.0.0.252, but I'm getting a reply from 10.0.20.188; which is an dynamic DHCP allocated IP to general devices.

```
C:\Users\drodecker>ping pbx

Pinging pbx.office.relevantads.com [10.1.1.211] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.20.188: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.20.188: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.20.188: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.20.188: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 10.1.1.211:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Comment: Check your routing tables. Could be your pc or the router.

Comment: This is probably the default route for the network you are trying to reach. Paste the result of `route PRINT`

Comment: Okay... I see it in the route print.  DOH!.. of course (idiot check).

Comment: Is `10.0.20.188` the ip address of the client you're pinging FROM? Also, what subnet mask is in use?

Comment: Apparently that's MY ip.  So is this a windows default way to timeout a packet or a facet of ping in Windows CMD?

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE ANSWER:**
Your PC is trying to resolve the Ethernet MAC address of the next-hop interface, but it can not find none (eg: the target PC is powered off). So it reports a "Destination host unreachable" ICMP message originating from its own interface.

**LONG ANSWER**
An IP-over-Ethernet network has two complementary network addresses: a non-routable, link-layer physical addressing (the MAC address) and a routable, network-layer logical addressing (the IP address).

When trying to ping another hosts, your PC must:

1. decide, by virtue of the routing table, the outgoing interface
2. determine the MAC address of the next-hop Ethernet interface (using the ARP protocol)
3. send a packed with the next-hop interface as the destination MAC address and with the target IP address as the final destination

Point n.2 is were behavior can diverge:

- if the remote host is on the local network, the next-hop Ethernet
  interface *is* the final destination you are trying to reach (eg: if
  my PC has IP 10.0.0.1 /24 and I am trying to ping PC with IP address
  10.0.0.2, the next-hop interface is that of the target computer);
- if the remote host is on a remote network, the next-hop Ethernet interface is that of the gateway interface (eg: if my PC has IP 10.0.0.1 /24 and I am trying to ping PC with IP address 10.10.10.1 /24 and that remote network can be reached using local router 10.0.0.254 /24, the next-hop interface is that of the router).

So, if your ping failed with a reply from your own PC interface, we have two possibility:

1. you are trying to ping a local address: this address is not replying to your PC ARP requests and, after a timeout, your PC inform you that the target Ethernet address can not be found.
2. you are trying to ping a remote address: your configured gateway for that address (eg: your default gateway) is not responding to your PC ARP requests. After a timeout, your PC inform you that the target Ethernet address can not be found.